# how to update ca-bundle.crt with local company-root.crt

Tags: rhel, rpm, curl, ssl, certificates

I am on RHEL 6.9

When I run the command
`sudo rpm --import https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc`

I get the following message

```
 curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
error: https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc: import read failed(2).
```

I have tried to use `-k` and `--insecure` both fail with something like `--inecure: unknown option`

I am behind a company firewall intercepts all TLS/SSL certs and replaces it with it's own.

Question: how do I get around this problem?

- I have a company `rootCert.crt` on my desktop is there a way to make this the default system cert? Would it fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the certificate in PEM format to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/` then run

```
# sudo update-ca-trust
```

This will import the certificate into the Redhat trust store. You might also need to enable the trust store before running the above with the command:

```
# update-ca-trust enable
```

To convert the key to PEM format check out this link:
[How to convert SSL/TLS certificate from .crt to .pem format](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/530033)

Further information from Redhat on adding the key to the truststore, this doesn't talk about converting to PEM format but it all depends on the original format of your CRT.

[How to install a CA certificate on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 and later](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1519813)

Comment: right now the cert is in .crt format. Could you add an explanation on how to convert it? Thanks!

Comment: try the redhat process first on this page https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1519813

Comment: Just a quick note: I had to use `update-ca-trust force-enable` to get this to work... Also, I cannot access the redhat links because I do not have an account...(I found the conversion on stackexchange) ☺ Thanks again!